# Understanding Box plots

Tags: visualization, data-analysis

I am new to box plots and I am trying to understand it. Consider the following figures :

[image]

According to my understanding, outliers will exist after the max. line and before the min. line. So according to the above figures,  we can see that outliers exist ( except for the EXT_Source 2 and EXT_Source 3 attributes) , which are labelled as black small circles after the max. value of each variable, am I right ??

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation of a boxplot is correct.

But outlier definition in general terms is subjective... to simplify the idea let´s consider just the top outliers (but probably you should consider the bottom ones too): you could use the 1% top values to consider them outliers, or do as the boxplot does and take the ones that exceed Q3 + 1.5 IQR, or do as Tukey and consider Q3 + 3IQR.

If you use R, you could leverage this chapter of the [Data Science Live Book](https://livebook.datascienceheroes.com/data-preparation.html#treatment_outliers)